# Fast check if polygon contains point between dataframes

Tags: pandas, performance, dataframe, polygon, contains

I have two dataframes. One contains a column of Polygons, taken from an image of polygon shapes. Each polygon has a set of coordinates. This dataframe also has a "segment-id" column. I have another dataframe, containing a column of Points, also with coordinates. These Points represent pixels from the same image of Polygon shapes, and therefore have the same coordinate system. I want to give every Point the "segment-id" of the Polygon which contains it. Every Polygon contains at least one Point.

Currently, I achieve this by using a nested for loop:

```py
    for i, row in enumerate(point_df.itertuples(), 0):
        point = pixel_df.at[i, 'geometry']

        for j in range(len(polygon_df)):
              polygon = polygon_df.iat[j, 0]

              if polygon.contains(point):
                  pixel_df.at[i, 'segment_id'] = polygon_df.at[j, 'segment_id']
              else:
                  pass
```

This is extremely slow. For 100 Points, it takes around 10 seconds. I need a faster way of doing this. I have tried using apply but it is still super slow.

Hope someone can help me out, thanks very much.

Comment: Can you post a disassembly or instruction trace of the slow part (`poly.contains(point)`)?

Comment: I was thinking the for loops were the slow part. But I'll try get this just now, I don't have much experience using debugging tools

Answer (score 0):

For fast "is point inside polygon":

Preparation: In the code that obtains the data describing the polygons; using all the vertices, find the minimum and maximum y-coord, and minimum and maximum x-coord; and store that with the polygon's data.

1) Using the point's coords and the polygon's "minimum and maximum x and y" (pre-determined during preparation); do a "bounding box" test. This is just a fast way to find out if the point is definitely not inside the polygon (so you can skip the more expensive steps most of the time).

2) Set a "yes/no" flag to "no"

3) For each edge in the polygon; determine if a horizontal line passing through the point would intersect with the edge, and if it does determine the x-coord of the intersection. If the x-coord of the intersection is less than the point's x-coord, toggle (with NOT) the "yes/no" flag. Ignore "horizontal line passes through a vertex" during this step.

4) For each vertex, compare its y-coord with the point's y-coord. If they're the same you need to look at both edges coming from that vertex to determine if the edge's vertices are in the same y direction. If the edge's vertices are in the same y direction (if the edges form a 'V' shape or upside-down 'V' shape) ignore the vertex. Otherwise (if the edges form a '<' or '>' shape), if the vertex's x-coord is less than the point's x-coord, toggle the "yes/no" flag.

After all this is done; that "yes/no" flag will tell you if the point was in the polygon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think poly.contains(points) already does most of that. It was more a quicker way of iterating through the two dataframes. I don't think the if statement is what's slowing it down. But thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: @D.Smith: I can (almost) guarantee that the `poly.contains(point)` is a festering mess that causes CPU to execute millions of instructions. It's why I suggested posting a disassembly or instruction trace before - not so much because I wanted to see it, but because I wanted you to see how horrifying a "designed for convenience" language is for performance. ;-)

Comment: @D.Smith: For a rough estimate; with most languages (assembly, C, C++, C#, Java, ..) I'd be extremely disappointed if I failed to do the above algorithm several million times per second (on one CPU alone). Even for python I'd still expect "almost 1 million per second" with good code; and the loop overhead is likely to be nothing (the outer loop only happens 100 times, and the only thing that looks potentially expensive in the inner loop is the `poly.contains(point)`).